# Computing the circumference, area, and ratio of circumference to area of a circle

Tags: python

Studying for a CS test and basically I have to follow instructions that are similar to this.

> Write a program, that is a file containing a main function followed by
>   a call to the main, and name the program ratio.py. The basic structure
>   of the program should look like this:
>
> ```
> def main():
>     ...
>     return
>
> main() where the ellipsis indicates where you should place the code that performs following computations:
> ```
>
> -you should prompt the user for an integer value corresponding to the
>   radius of a circle. Do this with code similar to:
>               radius = int(input("circle radius? "))
>
> - compute the circumference of the circle using the formula c = 2 πr where r is the radius and c is the circumference. Use the value of
>     3.14159 for π
> - compute the area of the circle using the formula c = πr2
> - print the ratio of the circumference to the area (the ratio of a to b is a divided by b)

Here is what I have written so far. I got the circumference and the area but how do I get it to make a ratio between the two and print the ratio.

```
def main():
   radius = int(input("circle radius? "))
   pi = 3.14159
   r = radius
   c = 2*pi*r
   print(2*pi*r)
   a = pi*r*r
   print(pi*r*r)
   ratio = c / a
   return(ratio)
   print("the ratio of the circumference to the area is",ratio)
main()
```

The ultimate goal is to get something like this:

- $ python3 ratio.py
- circle radius? 2
- the ratio of the circumference to the area is ????
- where ???? is replaced by the actual ratio.

Comment: Are we back again? Try to avoid having so many questions closed; this one is a lot better already but appears to miss an error message. What goes wrong, what do you expect to happen instead?

Comment: You should **edit** your existing questions to improve them rather than posting new ones. Asking substantially the same question repeatedly is a good way to get an automated question ban.

Comment: I tried to edit it with what the result of the function should be like, hope it helps

Comment: (You also shouldn't use `math.pi` when the instructor tells you to use an exact value for `pi`.)

Comment: Your function returns the result. You throw it away. You should print it. Consider going through beginning of [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/) or excellent [book for beginners](http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/thinkcspy/toc.html) .

Comment: A function can't do anything after it returns. Move the `print` before the `return` (if you even want to return anything; the spec doesn't tell you to.)

Comment: Good luck with your test! You may want to try https://codereview.stackexchange.com for future code reviews

Comment: (but it looks like you're getting some help here already, so it's all good)

Comment: @d3vid: codereview is for code that works.

Answer (score 1):

You are extremely close to solving this. Here are a couple ideas to help you finish it:

1. `import` statements should generally go at the top of the file, not inside a function. They will work in the function, but it is poor form. This was probably not taught in class, but you get used to seeing particular patterns as you read other people's code.
2. As a matter of style, Python generally uses capital letters for names of constants, so `PI=3.14159` is more common than pi=3.14159. This is minor and works either way. It is a good style to adhere to, since it will help make your code match others' code.
3. You need to calculate the area using the equation given to you: a = PI*r*r  (NOTE - the original question incorrectly uses 'c' for the area. 'c' is the circumference.)
4. You need to return c/a, which is the ratio that was requested.
5. You probably need to print out the return value for testing. You can do that by storing the value returned by main() in a variable and then printing it.

Here is how to return a value from your main() function:

```
def main():
    ...
    return c/a

ratio = main()
print(ratio)
# or...
print("The ratio is:", ratio)
```

Comment: He actually needs to define `pi`. It is the requirement.

Comment: Can you explain more of how exactly to do that last step. Also thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @user3283574 `result = main()` then `print(result)`.

Answer (score 0):

it's odd that you do `c = (2*math.pi*r)` when you have pi declared as a variable above two lines. Doing `math.pi` goes to python's math library and digs up a more accurate version of pi. For all intents and purposes, you are just completely not using that `pi` variable.
see http://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html for more information.

Furthermore, you do the same computation twice.

```
c = 2*math.pi*r
return(2*math.pi*r)
```

c just ends up being garbage collected (which is to say, the computer does the computation then INTO THE TRASH IT GOES) and never being used. It would be better to simply `return c`

For scoping issues, which I'm sure you wouldn't really know about as a beginner, put `import math` above your main function, unindented.

just for future reference though, SO tends to be for isolated problems that you have spotted in code; not for a full code review. A more acceptable question would be along the lines of "my function is returning an unexpected value", not "my function is not working"